# libgdx zoom/drag inside rectangle

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I am using scene2d for a board game. I want the board to be zoomable and movable inside its assigned rectangular part of the screen, while the rest of the screen stays the same.

I have tried to use a separate stage for the board, but haven't found a way to initialise viewports and cameras that does this correctly.

I tried the following code in `Screen.resize(int width, int height)` as a test, but the boardStage becomes stretched vertically, and when zoomed in (like here), it fills the whole screen.

```
hudStage.setViewport(8, 12, true, 0, 12, width, height);
boardStage.setViewport(8, 8, true, 0, 10, width, width); 

OrthographicCamera cam = (OrthographicCamera) boardStage.getCamera();
cam.zoom =.5f;
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have implemented a similar zoom for our board game. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.peakgames.mobile.rummi.android

We are using a second camera which is zoomed:

- A scissorStack is used to clip the second camera rendering area.
- Second camera is enabled only when there is a touch/drag on the board.
- we are changing the camera position as the user drags on the board.

hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the way to go. If I understand this correctly the clipBounds parameter to calculateScissors uses stage coordinates and not screen coordinates. That means that I will have to recalculate the clipBounds area every time the camera is panned or zoomed, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what we are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a scene2d [ScrollPane](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html) instead of a new Stage.  I'm not entirely sure how you'd do the zooming with this, but I think the scaling stuff should work.

Comment: If I had no need for zoom, this seems like a good solution, but zooming may complicate things.